# Android Virtual Keyboard Position

Tags: android, layout, keyboard, overlap

I have two activity forms in Android Studio. I am trying to get it so the form will scroll and when the virtual keyboard pops up it won't cover the contents. For example:

[image: Login]

As you can see the keyboard overlaps two buttons underneith the two text boxes. How can I make it so it doesn't do this?

I have tried using  `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the manifest file but it seems to still cover the buttons.

Cheers.

Comment: You can use AdjustSpan/ Adjustresize attribute in Android manifest file for that activity

Comment: I have tried using  android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan" etc and it doesn't do anything

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to play with the `windowSoftInputMode`.

```
<activity android:windowSoftInputMode="stateVisible|adjustResize" . . . >
```

See developer docs [here](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

I've found that if `android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"` in the manifest doesn't work then you probably don't have `android:fitsSystemWindows="true"` in the root view on your layout.xml(in my case I had the issue with ConstraintLayout but I know it also works for relativeLayout, I'm not sure about the other Layouts)